# How to "logic:iterate" just one object?

Tags: java, jsp, collections, struts, javabeans

So, I have this code:

```
logic:iterate name="nameForm" property="name" id="nameId" indexId="index"
bean:write name="nameId" property="field1"/
bean:write name="nameId" property="field2"/
```

This works great because I'm receiving a "table of objects" so I can do the iterate without issues.

Now, on another page I need to do the same but the issue is I am not receiving a "table of objects" but an object itself.
I tried it nonetheless and - as expected - got the error: *Cannot create iterator for this collection*

I've RTFM'd and I'm still more confused than before.
I get how the "name" inside the "logic:iterate" points to the form name in the struts-config, now I need to do the same with just **one** bean, any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a bean name with the `<logic:iterate>`, but it should be a collection or array, or implement [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html). [Here](http://www.mkyong.com/struts/struts-logic-iterate-example/)'s the example of the tag usage.

> In Struts, you can use `logic:iterate` tag to iterate over collections. Here’re the example:
>
> #### Iterate over a list/array (Object)
>
> Create a normal list with few `"user"` objects and store it into `HttpServletRequest` as name `"listUsers"`.
>
> ```
> public class User{
>
>   String username;
>   String url;
>
>     //getter and setter methods
> }
>
>
> ...
>
> public class PrintMsgAction extends Action{
>
>   public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping,ActionForm form,
>       HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) 
>         throws Exception {
>
>       List<User> listUsers = new ArrayList<User>();
>
>       listUsers.add(new User("user1", "http://www.user1.com"));
>       listUsers.add(new User("user2", "http://www.user2.com"));
>       listUsers.add(new User("user3", "http://www.user3.com"));
>       listUsers.add(new User("user4", "http://www.user4.com"));
>
>       request.setAttribute("listUsers", listUsers);
>
>       return mapping.findForward("success");
>   }
>
> }
> ```
>
> Inside the logic tag, you can use the `"name"` attribute (`listUsers`) to get the list value, while `"property"` attribute to display the object property value.
>
> ```jsp
> <%@taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean"%>
> <%@taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic" prefix="logic"%>
> <html>
> <head>
> </head>
> <body>
> <h1>Struts <logic:iterate> example</h1>
>
> <logic:iterate name="listUsers" id="listUserId">
> <p>
>   List Users <bean:write name="listUserId" property="username"/> , 
>   <bean:write name="listUserId" property="url"/>
> </p>
> </logic:iterate>
>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```
>
> [image]

Comment: The problem is I don't have a list or a table. On this part of the program I'm just sending one object and I'd like to continue it that way; is there any way I can point to just one object or do I have to create an array of 1 item for it to work?

Comment: @Johns You can wrap an object into array if you want to iterate this array containing that object.

Comment: That's the thing, I would rather learn how to properly show just one item/object instead of cheating and creating a list of one item because I don't know better...

Comment: @Johns You can show it in many different ways, but you have chosen to ask how to use `<logic:iterate>` tag to accomplish desired.

Comment: Really? After reading all that that's what you got? My bad, I don't know what I was expecting.